# Passing Data between Arbitrary amounts of Fragments via one Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, software-design

I have an application design question regarding passing data between fragments. I have an application using the navigation drawer layout, with various "sub applications" that perform standalone functions (for example, a calculators app, with unrelated "sub apps" for income tax calculations, metric/imperial conversions, etc).

For a given calculator, I'd have a data entry/selection fragment and a data presentation fragment that displays the calculation in some meaningful type of way. Thus, my only activity in the application is the MainActivity holding the navigation drawer and content pane. The question is: what is the best way to design the application such that the various calculators pass data to their data representation fragments, say on the click of a button? It is my understanding that fragment are not designed to pass data between each other, but rather rely on an activity to facilitate that via some type of callback listener. However, with only one activity and an arbitrary amount of calculators, how does this work? Am I supposed to create a separate activity for each calculator? If so, how does this affect the navigation drawer?

Note that the example is completely made up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First approach is to create some singleton class that will handle fragments' data--so fragments and activities can send data to it and subscribe for updates. Second approach is to use intent broadcasting, sending/receiving data using `Intent.putExtra` and `Intent.getExtras`

Comment: Check out the publish / subscribe pattern, in particular frameworks such as eventbus. I've use it, but there are a lot of other options out there. A quick google search can give you several possibilities: https://www.google.com/search?q=pubsub+for+android&oq=pubsub+for+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3499j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=publish+subscribe+for+android

Comment: Or... you can use Interfaces, as suggested here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I'll have to look into the subscriber pattern a little more, I'm having trouble grasping it - thankfully there are tons of resources available. @kentarosu that's the first thing I tried, but it's problematic because of the amount of "sub-applications" I have, I'll end up implementing a bajillion interfaces in my main activity.