# Android Publish/Subscribe Singleton Example

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, software-design

Can someone provide a simple example of using the Publish/SUbscribe singleton pattern to pass information between fragments. Last week I asked about [passing data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749483/passing-data-between-arbitrary-amounts-of-fragments-via-one-activity?noredirect=1#comment34680408_22749483) for the scenario below and this method was suggested; I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

> I have an application using the navigation drawer layout, with various
>   "sub applications" that perform standalone functions (for example, a
>   calculators app, with unrelated "sub apps" for income tax
>   calculations, metric/imperial conversions, etc). For a given
>   calculator, I'd have a data entry/selection fragment and a data
>   presentation fragment that displays the calculation in some meaningful
>   type of way. Thus, my only activity in the application is the
>   MainActivity, holding the navigation drawer and content pane. The
>   question is: what is the best way to design the application such that
>   the various calculators pass data to their data representation
>   fragments, say on the click of a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the examples in the internet s...ks, with their UML diagrams absolutely unclear to beginners and plenty of code where only experienced one can understand why using this not that, one not another... So, let's construct moving step by step and thinking logically.

**First,** you need to create some kind of storage in your singleton class - to make data not depend on fragments' lifecycle. Depending on purpose of your app it may be different kinds of collections or just primitives. Add such fields into you singleton, for example:

```
double conversionRate, taxRate;
int securityNumber;
.... // and so on
```

Now you need some method of your singleton which will update these data. Let's call it `updateData()`. Every time when some data in any of your fragments is changed by user, this fragment should invoke:

```
Singleton.getInstance().updateData(dataType, data);
```

As arguments let's put type of data and some object that contains these data.

**Second,** on every update you need to update data in other presentation fragments, right? So this `updateData()` method should run through list of fragments running at the moment and send new data to each. How to implement it? -- Very easy, via callback method. For that, you will need to:

1) create public interface a kind of `Updateable` with one method: `public void onUpdate(int dataType, Data data)`

2) implement this interface on every fragment by `implements Updateable` after class name

3) implement its only method `onUpdate()` in class body. In this implementation, each fragment will consider, first, whether it needs to use data of a given dataType, second, handle these received data (e. g. change its textview value):

```
@Override
onUpdate(int dataType, Data data){
   if (dataType == DATA_TAX_RATE){
      textViewTaxRate.setText(String.parseInt(data.getValue()));
   }

}
```

**Third,** how your singleton will know to whom it should send updated data? Very easy: just add a storage that will contain all fragments as `Updateable` objects in it:

```
List<Updateable> listeners = new ArrayList<Updateable>;
```

and add two additional methods to register and unregister objects (e. g. your fragments) as listeners. In first method you should just add a listener into mentioned list, in second remove it:

```
public void registerListener(Updateable listener){
  if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
     listeners.add(listener);
  }
}

public void unregisterListener(Updateable listener){
  if (listener != null && listeners.contains(listener)){
     listeners.remove(listeners.indexOf(listener));
  }
}
```

Now, each fragment which wants to receive updates (i. e. implements Updateable interface) should register as a listener right after creation and resume:

```
Singleton.getInstance().registerListener(this);
```

and unregister on `onDestroy` or when it doesn't need to listen for updates anymore:

```
Singleton.getInstance().unregisterListener(this);
```

*N.B.: to prevent memory leaks, you should unregister a listener when you are going not to use this object anymore. Otherwise reference to it will be kept in listeners list making it inaccessible to garbage collector!*

After we created methods to add and remove listeners, let's return to singleton's method `updateData()` mentioned before. Its main purpose is to store new data and send updates to all listeners, so let's implement it:

```
public void updateData(int dataType, Data data){
   // store new data
   if (dataType == DATA_TAX_RATE){
       this.taxRate = data.getValue();
   }

   .....

   // then iterate through listeners and send updated data to them
   for (Updateable listener : listeners){
       try {
          listener.onUpdate(dataType, data);
       } catch (Throwable e) {}
   } 
}
```

Now, every time user updates some data in any of your fragments, or data are updated by calculation, just call `Singleton.getInstance().updateData(...)` from this fragment -- new data will be stored in singleton and broadcasted to other fragments automatically.

==================================================================

*Disclaimer: this is not exact implementation of Observer design pattern, just its simplified version to be more clear and understandable for beginners. That's why I don't use common names such as `Observer`, `notify` etc. It's just working example for first step of understanding common design patterns more deeply.*

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears up a ton of confusion that I had regarding implementing this design pattern - it's very hard to grasp when first learning it. One thing that isn't clear to me is how the host activity can be "told" to change the fragment currently being viewed. For example, when an update is received within and `Updateable` fragment, how can it relay to the hosting activity that  the fragment being displayed needs to be replaced? This is intuitive with a callback listener, but what if there are many fragments that would require the activity to implement their callback listener?

Comment: If your have several fragments that every does its own task, there is no need to implement mentioned interface in activity. Singleton object will be absolutely separate and it will hold references to fragments that listen to updates--and broadcast updates directly to these fragments.

Comment: To make singleton object separate and independent on activity lifecycle, keep reference to it in application object, no activity object.

Comment: If your activity should manipulate fragments depending on updated data, it also should receive updates via `onUpdate()` and make such manipulations. In classical Observer pattern, updates are a kind of broadcast messages. Every receiver (observer) should decide by itself what to do with received data or just ignore them if they are out of its interest.